# lodash nested array value filter overwriting original values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, lodash

i have tried multi nested filter i got the output correctly but the original data is also filtered replacing. please check my code i don't know where i'm doing the mistake can any one help me how to solve the problem.

is there any better way to do filter in java script? I am developing this in React.js

Filter possibility are country name, country meta tag,cityIds. cityIds -> name,meta tag, portIds, portIds ->name,meta tag

https://jsfiddle.net/25sn49v8/

```
const country = [
  {
    "_id":"59b3b419424d6751ceafe984",
    "name":"india country",
    "metaTags":[
      {
        "id":1,
        "text":"india country"
      },
      {
        "id":2,
        "text":"india"
      }
    ],
    "cityIds":[
      {
        "_id":"59c38704850f915d9715b93a",
        "name":"chennai city",
        "portIds":[
          {
            "_id":"59dc73d7f8c3033054e34fca",
            "name":"chennai port",

          },
          {
            "_id":"59df23af5a4fcc1d91201894",
            "name":"Port",
            "metaTags":[
              {
                "text":"Port",
                "id":1
              }
            ],

          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id":"59c4a9c0841f767b0ba80652",
        "name":"Nungambakkam",
        "metaTags":[
          {
            "id":1,
            "text":"Nungambakkam"
          }
        ],
        "portIds":[
          {
            "_id":"59c4ec17841f767b0ba806a3",
            "name":"mumbai city",
            "metaTags":[
              {
                "id":1,
                "text":"Mu"
              }
            ],

          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id":"59b3b419424d6751ceafe984",
    "name":"australia country",
    "metaTags":[
      {
        "id":1,
        "text":"australia country"
      },
      {
        "id":2,
        "text":"australia"
      }
    ],
    "cityIds":[
      {
        "_id":"59c38704850f915d9715b93a",
        "name":"Sydney city",
        "metaTags":[
          {
            "text":"Sydney",
            "id":1
          },
          {
            "text":"city",
            "id":1
          }
        ],
        "portIds":[
          {
            "_id":"59dc73d7f8c3033054e34fca",
            "name":"Sydney port",
            "metaTags":[
              {
                "text":"Sydney port",
                "id":1
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "_id":"59df23af5a4fcc1d91201894",
            "name":"Sydney two",
            "metaTags":[
              {
                "text":"Sydney",
                "id":1
              }
            ],

          }
        ],

      },
      {
        "_id":"59c4a9c0841f767b0ba80652",
        "name":"perth",
        "metaTags":[
          {
            "id":1,
            "text":"perth"
          }
        ],
        "portIds":[
          {
            "_id":"59c4ec17841f767b0ba806a3",
            "name":"perth port",
            "metaTags":[
              {
                "id":1,
                "text":"perth xxx"
              }
            ],

          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]



const filterTree = (filter, list) => {
  return _.filter(list, (item) => {
    //console.log(item,"AAAA")
    if (_.includes(_.toLower(item.name), _.toLower(filter))) {
      //console.log(item,"11111")
      return true;
    }
    else if(_.findIndex( item.metaTags, function(o) { return _.includes(_.toLower(o.text), _.toLower(filter))})  >=0 ){
      return true;
    }
    else if (item.cityIds) {
      //console.log(item.cityIds,"22222")

      item.cityIds = filterTree(filter, item.cityIds);
      return !_.isEmpty(item.cityIds);
    }
    else if (item.portIds) {
      //console.log(item,"33333",!_.isEmpty(item.portIds))
      item.portIds = filterTree(filter, item.portIds);
      return !_.isEmpty(item.portIds);
    }
  });
};


console.log(filterTree('perth xxx', country),"output");

console.log( country);
```

Comment: I don't actually get your question but as far as I understand, You should know that in JavaScript values are not copied when doing `a = b`. Instead they are referenced (`b` is referenced to `a`). So any changes you make in `b` will also be reflected in `a`

Comment: is there any way to solve this

Comment: because i need to this in on change event .

Comment: i'm not having idea how to do this filter nested name and meta tages